# JScrollPane wont appear alone

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I want to add a jscroll pane in a jframe that is not alone with the something it scrolls through
because whenever I add a JScrollPane I must make

```
JScrollPane p = new JScrollPane();
p.createVerticalScrollBar();
fr.setContentPane(p);
fr.revalidate();
```

if I just added it It doesn't appear like:

```
fr.add(p);
```

that doesn't appear..

I don't want the scrollpane to appear alone in the frame but with other things maybe a button and a textfield..

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The default is for the scroll bar to only be shown when needed (which I prefer). If the component you add doesnt exceed the space of the scroll pane, the scroll bar won't show. If you want the scroll bar to always appear, then you need to `p.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);`. Also I don't see you adding a component to the scroll pane. It should be a `JPanel` you add. The `JPanel` should have all your components.

Comment: My understanding of this question is: "I have a frame, and this frame should contain a JScrollPane AND some other components". But of course, when you set the ScrollPane as the ContentPane of the Frame, then ONLY the ScrollPane will be visible. For the case that my interpretation of the question is correct, I'll leave this pointer here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
       public class SampleFrame {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){  
     public void run()  
    {  
    createAndShowGUI();  
    }  
    });  
    }  
    public static void createAndShowGUI()  
   {  
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame with ScrollBar");  
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
  JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5,20);  
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);  
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);  
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);  
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);  
   frame.setSize(300, 200);  
   frame.setVisible(true);  
   }  
}

  try This
```

Comment: wow thanks it works but did you forget to add the jtextfield?